# Bootstrap alert line breaks on IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `alert` that displays error messages in a fixed position at the top of my web app:

```
<div class="alert-messages">
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" title="Dimiss">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>A somewhat long error message that causes multiline in IE10</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for `alert-messages`:

```
.alert-messages {
 position: fixed;
 right: 24px;
 top: 21px;
}
```

The problem is that Internet Explorer always breaks the last word into a separate line, this doesn't happen on Chrome or Firefox and I have to support IE10+ for this project.

This is how it looks for Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

And this is how it looks on IE10:

[image]

Here's the MVCE version in plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IGDGkKgFUBXxOpM0zwHC?p=preview you can even try with shorter messages and still reproduce this.

Comment: have you tried setting a width?

Comment: I considered it as an option, but if the width of the `alert` is larger than the width of the text inside it, it leaves an empty red space that overlaps with other elements.

Comment: Perhaps `white-space:nowrap`?

Comment: I just set a width on the alert in IE using the link you advised and it does work and give you the the text on on line if you set it to 475px. But I do get what you mean.  You could look at setting a `min-width` and a `max-width` if that helps?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes! that did it! Feel free to post it as an answer so it might help anyone else who runs into this in the future.